# Grails 2.4 multipart/form-data and SSL security error

Tags: grails

I have a web page with https on Tomcat and SSL created with java keytool. Now we can't upload files when use multipart/form-data in gsp. The logs say
`Error when matching URL mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?]:class "org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package`

My current solution is; send the string encoded in base64 and convert the string to file in the controller. Can someone find the best way to solve this problem?